# How to Run Python Instantiated Class methods

Tags: python, class, methods, command-line, instances

Noob question on running Python file Instantiated Class Methods:
I want to run the method test_method() in the class TestClass() to verify algorithm() works.
How do I run this code from the python command line?

File Name: algo.py

```
import unittest
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime

def algorithm(a,b):
    c = a+b
    return c

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_method(self):
        a = np.array(1.1)
        b = np.array(2.2)
        algo_return = algorithm(a,b) 

        self.assertAlmostEqual(algo_return[0], 3.3)
```

I have attempted,

```
import algo
test_method = algo
TestClass = algo.TestClass()
```

But the third line yielded the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/Wing101.app/Contents/Resources/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
# Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 191, in __init__
(self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'algo.TestClass'>: runTest
```

I am using python2.7, wings101 IDE.

I'm looking for an answer like (But this doesn't work):

```
import algo
TestClass.test_method()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Then you'll be able to run your file simply as "python algo.py", and that will run your test.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) for more information on using the Python unittest framework.